# IndexError: index 43462904 is out of bounds for size 43462904

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, compiler-errors, index-error

I have a data set that have 43.462.904 milions of records. I try to do a group by with two variables and do an average of the third one.

The fnuction is: `df1 = df.groupby(["var1", pd.Grouper(key="var2"freq="MS")]).mean()`

The error that exit is the follow: `IndexError: index 43462904 is out of bounds for size 43462904`

The error is because I have a long dataset? The function with a few data function

Answer (score 0):

An array of length N can be indexed with 0 ... N-1:

> arr = [0,1,2]
>
> arr[0]: 0
>
> arr[1]: 1
>
> arr[2]: 2
>
> len(arr): 3

In this example you try to access arr[3] which is invalid as it's the N+1st entry in the array.

Comment: In your example I understood the concept, but in mine not. Can i fix my error?

Comment: I doubt it has to do with size. try your code with a tiny or small example dataset. Append that to your question, if the problem persists with that. It's hard to answer your question differently as we know little to nothing about your data(frames)

Comment: I already tryed with a small dataset and there isn't a problem. To not create a lot of batch, I prefer use the function on all data

Comment: So can you amend your question with a complete, verifyable example of your code? At best such that we can reproduce the error... but with 10M datasets, that's hard. Are your big data structured differently somewhere than your example dataset, thus generated differently? Are indexes inferred from some numbers read from files? Are there assumptions that number of lines in a file equals number of datasets (that easily breaks with empty lines)?

Comment: I found 2 row with NaN, probabily the error is this

Comment: Make a small example which also contains NaNs and test your code with that :)